# Reliable file uploader using Ruby on Rails and Amazon S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, amazon-s3

I am looking to create a file uploader using Ruby on Rails that must have the following features :

- Work for any file type
- Get upload progress

  - I used an apache module to track progress but flash solutions are acceptable
- Use Amazon S3 as the filesystem

  - Rails creates a RackMultipart file in the tmp folder that needs to be moved to S3 wondering is there is a better way
- Extremely reliable

  - My current implementation occasionally either fails to track progress properly or sometimes the RackMultipart file isn't created (Rails 2.3.8)

My system is Rails 2.3.8, Ruby 1.8.7 Enterprise, Apache.

Comment: any insights or recommendations ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a similar SO question:

[Ruby on Rails: upload files with progress bar and checking of filesize before upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3496273/ruby-on-rails-upload-files-with-progress-bar-and-checking-of-filesize-before-upl)

---

I've tried all of these and have had a problem with each one:

http://timmyc.posterous.com/uploadify-on-rails-with-paperclip

http://railsillustrated.com/screencast-file-uploads-progress-in-rails-passenger.html

http://railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/07/21/uploadify-and-rails23/

http://jimneath.org/2008/05/15/swfupload-paperclip-and-ruby-on-rails/

---

AFAIK it's not even good practice do upload like this. Upload and use delayed job to handle it in the background `workers' are supposed to do this on heroku.

Comment: delayed_job is an interesting idea. But how does it work if I have multiple webservers and multiple (different) processing servers? Delayed job processing happens on the proc servers and the RackMultipart file will be on webservers.

Comment: Heroku solves the problem by loading the application in a slug 'single file' that is run in a cloud so it doesn't matter if the application is spread out on servers. but you are trying to use a different production so I cannot answer that.

Comment: Heroku sounds cool. I am using Amazon EC2. Any insight or recommendations with Uploadify or YUI Uploader ? I overlooked them earlier due to Flash hesitations but the use of Flash seems inevitable to avoid browser compatibility issues